# Reporting Services Deployment Problem Deploying from VS 2005 to RS 2008

Tags: deployment, reporting-services, datasource

I've got a report that works perfectly in development previews. But when I deploy I get the following error:

In the Dev Environment the Error displayed is:

> Error 4   The data source 'myDataSource'
>   cannot be found.  c:\reporting services
>   projects\reports\rest_of_path\my_report.rdl
>     0   0

On the reporting services side the error it shows is:

> The data source connection information
>   has been deleted.
>   (rsInvalidDataSourceReference)

By itself the datasource deploys just fine and it's present on the server so it doesn't make sense that it "can't find" it.  What is going on?

---

P.s. I found a way to make it work on the server by manually assigning the datasource link that's lost in deployment.  But I'd rather not have to do this every time I deploy a new report.

1. go to Report Manager(http:///reports/pages/Folder.aspx)
2. Click on the Folder in which u have reports
3. U will be directed into contents tab where u will find Show Details at the right top corner
4. Click on Show Details
5. Check in the particular report and click the edit button corresponding to it
6. Go to the properties tab and click on it
7. U will find a menu on left hand side, click on Data Sources link
8. There u will find radio button selected for A share data source(by default) and a browse button.
9. Click on the browse button u will find the tree structure of the datasource and the reports folder.
10. select the datasource in the datasource folder and select OK.
    (From a post on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/622dc981-4378-4331-b2fc-e377660464df/)

Comment: Could you give more detail - what version of Reporting Services are you using etc.. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you upgrade the report files? the RDL spec changed between 2005 and 2008, you need to ensure that you are working with 2008 compatible tools if you are targeting 2008.

Comment: No. The report is still generated in 2005.  The only 2008 component is the report server.  We were hoping to do a phased transition...  Unfortunately, looks like probably won't work. :-(  Unless anyone else contradicts I'll accept this as the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with 2005, and to make it work I had to change the data source to use OLE DB and Sql Server Native Client 10.0.  Another strange quirk was that the data source had to not have spaces in the name.  I then had to reassign the report to use the new data source without spaces and then the 2005 rdl worked on the 2008 server.